# DatabaseUtils cursorRowToContentValues converts blob to string

Tags: android, blob, android-cursor

I just stumbled upon a problem with Android's `DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues` method. 
In the cursor the blob is correctly stored as a byte array. `cursor.getBlob()` also returns the correct value.
However after using the utils method to convert it, the `ContentValues` contain a string and calling `getAsByteArray` returns null, because there is no byte array with that key.

I couldn't find any bug reports for this, but I think this isn't intended?

Comment: Do you have some code to demonstrate the problem? The method supports blobs as long as the data is actually a blob and the cursor is a `AbstractWindowedCursor`.

Comment: The cursor is a self filled MatrixCursor. I will try to write a test for it on monday.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked into the DatabaseUtils sources. I wonder why they did it like this. It should at least be written in the doc!

Comment: Agree the Android sqlite documentation is not very good at places. Use the source, don't just trust the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The cursor is a self filled MatrixCursor.

That's the problem.

Here's the code for [`DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues()`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#710):

```
710    public static void cursorRowToContentValues(Cursor cursor, ContentValues values) {
711        AbstractWindowedCursor awc =
712                (cursor instanceof AbstractWindowedCursor) ? (AbstractWindowedCursor) cursor : null;
713
714        String[] columns = cursor.getColumnNames();
715        int length = columns.length;
716        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
717            if (awc != null && awc.isBlob(i)) {
718                values.put(columns[i], cursor.getBlob(i));
719            } else {
720                values.put(columns[i], cursor.getString(i));
721            }
722        }
723    }
```

Note the use of `AbstractWindowedCursor`. If the cursor isn't one, everything is treated as strings, including blobs.

Now, the inheritance graph for [`MatrixCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) is:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.database.AbstractCursor
       ↳    android.database.MatrixCursor
```

No `AbstractWindowedCursor` there.

Overall, the `DatabaseUtils` are there only for convenience. If they work for you, fine. If they don't work for you, then you'll have to roll your own util methods.